# When scrolling a part of my website, its goes over my header instead of under

Tags: html, css

Here is the main page of my website. http://puu.sh/d9HeI/dd63792292.png
But when i scroll down the content boxes goes over the header and not under.
http://puu.sh/d9HiQ/ba031bf256.png

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="Content-Box"> (First Box)
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.Content-Box {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: white;
top: 65px;
padding: 45px;
height: -70px;
text-align: center;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #888888;
}
```

Comment: try adding `z-index:100`

Comment: You should consider accepting more answers if your problem is resolved

Answer (score 1):

Adding `z-index` will bring the header on top of every `element`

add `z-index:100` to `header`

Answer (score 0):

you might have given the absolute position to the header or you must give the header z-index:5 or some positive integer value or give your container a z-index:-5 to a negative value to make the header come over the body or to take the body behind header

Answer (score 0):

You must specify  `position:fixed`  and `z-index`